# GWT send mail in development mode mail server problem

Tags: java, gwt, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail with gwt and java on the server with the buitin jetty on eclipse but I am getting the following error:

Cannot open and load mail server properties file.
Cannot send email. javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

does someone know what to configure to make it work??

Comment: Are you using Spring on the server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not GWT related problem. Test you email sending code in isolation (without GWT and Jetty).

Start with sample code and configure it's parameters to your need. You will also need to use a SMTP server to send emails this way.